# code coverage using blanketjs for Javascript AMD project

Tags: javascript, requirejs, code-coverage, blanket.js

I am trying to use blanket for my project which is built using requirejs - AMD pattern.

For example,
My Module A is requiring Module B, so as you know I don't include

```
<script src="moduleB"></script>
```

because requirejs gets that module by itself. In these cases how do I cover module B using blanket?

If I include script for Module B in my html then I am getting below error,

> "Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function
>   -------- "